# How to make VLC show single FLAC file containing many tracks as separate tracks

Tags: vlc-media-player, flac

I have a single `.flac` file that encompasses multiple tracks comprising a music album along with the corresponding `.cue` file. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with VLC player, and am trying to get VLC player to show the individual tracks and allow me to use the previous and next controls to move back and forth between tracks.  The problem I'm having is that when I open the single `.flac` file with VLC, it just shows a single track the duration of the entire album, and I'm unable to skip back and forth between tracks.  Is there any way to have VLC show the individual tracks contained within a `.flac` file without having to pre-split the `.flac` file into individual track files first?

Answer (score 5):

You need to open in VLC the cue file that came with the flac, rather than the flac file.
If it's missing, that might be one reason that VLC is having problems detecting the multi-tracks.

If VLC still doesn't work even when the cue file is opened, see:

[Split lossless audio (ape, flac, wv, wav) by cue file in Ubuntu](http://aidanjm.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/split-lossless-audio-ape-flac-wv-wav-by-cue-file/)
[Split APE and FLAC Files in Ubuntu and Add Tags by Cue File](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/04/split-ape-and-flac-files-in-ubuntu-and.html)

Comment: So the answer is: I don't know, VLC does not support multi-track FLAC files?

Comment: @hakre: The poster has abandoned his post, so we don't know the final resolution to his problem and whether it's related to his cue file or not.

Comment: Might be, however this interesting question would remain. I tried to find out more, however tooling support is not really optimal. Just was commenting.